# UDP - how get destination address for incoming datagram

Tags: java, android, udp

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet);
//packet.getDestAddress()
```

I want to get the IP address to which the datagram came.
I got no ideas.

Comment: Shouldn't you already know your ip-address?

Comment: @NomadMaker - Just about every computer has multiple IP addresses.  In the trivial sense; e.g. loopback.  Often in the non-trivial sense as well; e.g. machines with multiple physical NICs or virtual network interfaces.

Comment: How about getInetAddress() or getLocalAddress()?

Comment: @NomadMaker You have still not understood the question. When a host has multiple IP addresses a datagram can be received via any of them, and it can be of interest to know to which of them the datagram was addressed. This is not the same thing as the single IP address or hostname returned by either of those APIs.

Comment: The destination address of a UDP datagram is not available in Java.

Comment: DatagramSocket has a number of address methods. Why wouldn't one of the two methods I named Datagram#getInetAddress() or Datagram#getLocalAddress() show the destination address? There might be others, Datagram has a lot of methods for a fairly simple API. Of course, the last time I wrote a udp server was 40 years ago, in c.

Comment: @NomadMaker Because none of them returns the target address of a received datagram.  Please stop guessing. See the Javadoc. And there is no such method as `Datagram.getInetAddress()` or `Datagram.getLocalAddress()`, or indeed any such class as `Datagram`. You appear to be thinking of `DatagramSocket`, and you continue to completely ignore the issue of the target address of the datagram.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way to address this is to change

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
```

to

```
InetAddress localAddr = ...
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3000, localAddr);
```

That way your socket will bind to a specific IP address (rather than all local addresses) and it will only get packets addressed to that IP address.  If you want to receive packets addresses to multiple addresses AND distinguish the different IP addresses, you could create a distinct `DatagramSocket` for each IP address.

(The complexity of dealing with multiple sockets may cause you second thoughts as to whether you *really need to know* the target IP for incoming datagrams.)

Comment: I am doing broadcast messages to all network and want to reject my packets. I want use  Wi-Fi or AP without interacting with them directly (without knowing their IP).

Comment: You should be able to filter the packets based on where they are >>from<<.  But you do need to know what your machine's IP addresses are.